# algorithm for summing total item for categories

Tags: javascript, algorithm, angularjs

I have a set of data like 11112344411121, which each integer represent 4 category id. It will be loaded from the backend. so I use the function `countState` to count and categorize it.

```
$scope.countState = function(){
            $scope.countNote = 0;
            $scope.countQuote = 0;
            $scope.countProject = 0;
            $scope.countSkill = 0;
            for(var i = 0;i< $scope.postItem.length;i++){
                $loopObj = $scope.postItem[i].category_id;

                switch($loopObj)
                {
                case '1':
                  $scope.countNote++;
                  break;
                case '2':
                  $scope.countQuote++;
                  break;
                case '3':
                  $scope.countProject++;
                  break;
                case '4':
                  $scope.countSkill++;
                  break;
                }
            }

}
```

I have another function which update when the user insert something. The {{countNote}} didn't update. Why? $scope problem?

```
$scope.updateState = function(currentTab){

    alert(currentTab);

                        switch(currentTab)
                        {
                        case '1':
                          $scope.countNote++;
                          break;
                        case '2':
                          $scope.countQuote++;
                          break;
                        case '3':
                          $scope.countProject++;
                          break;
                        case '4':
                          $scope.countSkill++;
                          break;
                        }
}
```

or I should count it in backend?

Comment: Is countState getting called again?  I'd put an alert in that function to see, most likely that is happening and it is resetting the values to 0.

Comment: Where all the code is?? probably something is wrong with a part of code you are not showing here!

Comment: Could it be that the currentTab isn't a string? If it is numerical, you have to remove the single quotes in the case statements.